# Could not change color using configuration panel in vis js

Tags: javascript, vis.js

I created a network using Vis.js and I set the configuration panel to change colors however it did not work.[image]

I get the following error
[image]

Here is how I set my options

```
var options = {
      physics: {
        enabled: false
      },
      configure: {
        showButton: true,
      },
};
```

Here is a fiddle to reproduce the error:
https://jsfiddle.net/marouenbg/tLd87oa9/